# UWP BackgroundUploader.GetCurrentUploadsAsync gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, uwp, windows-10-universal

In my UWP App, I am using a BackgroundUploader from the BackgroundTransfer namespace, to upload some files to a server. Now when I close my app and reopen it, it loads all active uploads

```
IReadOnlyList<UploadOperation> uploads = null;

try
{
    uploads = await BackgroundUploader.GetCurrentUploadsAsync();
}
catch
{
    return;
}
```

My app now hangs for a few seconds on GetCurrentUploadsAsync, if there were uploads active (and are already completed). If i deploy the app and no uploads were processed, the GetCurrentUploadsAsync method is processing very quick without any "delay".

This behavior is only happening on Windows10 Mobile, on Desktop, I haven't seen this.

I don't know what this can be, and hope someone can help me.

Comment: maybe your are int he UI thread so you should try the following:
`uploads = await BackgroundUploader.GetCurrentUploadsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` this will prevent the async action to be executed in the context of the UI thread and instead use a thread from the threadpool.

Comment: Maybe i wasnt exact enough. The app is not hanging like a short freeze. The code execution is hanging, but it should retutn the (zero) transfers immediately.

Comment: when exactly is it hanging? Maybe this is due to the Mobile OS, it could execute such "requests" only at specific CPU cycls / time periods to save energy and not request those things immediately.

Comment: When i first deploy the app to the phone, and no upload was started, the GetCurrentUploadsAsync method runs very quickly. But if i made some uploads for the first time, from then this method is hanging everytime for some seconds, when it is called.

Comment: to be honest i have no experience with the BackgroundUploader. Could you show your upload code? Maybe you are not closing the `UploadOperation` object? From the described behavior it sounds like something in the background is still running or objects left unhandled.

Comment: I have forgot to say something, These Uploads are processed from a BackgroundTask. I have tested now with one Manual upload and there were no Problems. Now i will test it with only one upload from the BackgroundTask. Can it be, that the amount of Uploads are important?

Comment: @andy did you find the reason?

Comment: Not really, the problem occurs only on mobile and i fount out, that it is only a problem, if there were added many uploads. As i'm adding the Uploads from a BackgroundTask, everytime the BackgroundTask starts for adding new uploads, i check if there are active uploads available. I repeat this for every BackgrounTask activation for a few times, before i clean the Uploads (cancel them). Then starting to add new uploads. This way, the GetCurrentUploadsAsync() method does not stuck anymore. In my case, this is no problem for the workflow, in other scenarios, this might be not the best solution.